# integrity constraint violated - parent key not found even when row exists in parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, database-schema

I have two tables '`Session`' and '`target_system`'. one column in session table refers to `ID` column in `target_system` as the foreign key. I know I need to insert into 'target_system' first. I inserted that - even then this is giving

```
integrity constraint violated - parent key not found
```

Any idea what else can be the reason ?

Comment: Do you get the same error on both Oracle and MySQL systems? Table definitions please!

Comment: check the constraints properly. See my answer. and why do you have so many database tags?

Comment: @LalitKumarB It didnt help, I asked after doing all this. Also are there any irrelevant tags which I added

Comment: You have got multiple database tags. i assume you are working on one database at a time. why do you have to tag mysql, sql and oracle together? Which database are you working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have so many database tags in the question.

In Oracle, check the columns and corresponding constraints properly. You can query `user_constraints` and `user_cons_columns` -

```
SELECT * FROM user_constraints 
  WHERE WHERE table_name='<your_table_name>';

SELECT * FROM user_cons_columns 
  WHERE table_name='<your_table_name>';
```

Make sure the table_name is in UPPER CASE.